# how to separate bubble plot legend by variable in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I'm trying to build a bubble plot in ggplot2 that has two variables (Tmin and Tmax). The problem is that the legends are layered one on top of the other. I would like two separate legends. Also, I would like to adjust the bubble increment in the legend from 4 to 6 bubble sizes. Here's what I have thus far:

```
ggplot() + geom_path(data = westUS, aes(x = long, y = lat, group =        group)) + 
geom_point(data = myData, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = Tmin), pch = 1, color = "blue", stroke = 0.3) + scale_size_continuous(range = c(-2, 7.5)) + theme_bw() +
geom_point(data = myData, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = Tmax), pch = 1, color = "red", stroke = 0.3)
```

[This is how the plot looks currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hPRB.png)
Thanks!

Comment: Could you use dput to give us an example of the data?

Comment: Might need to add `guide = 'legend'`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe do one `size` legend and then a `color` legend for your group Tmin vs Tmax?